# Visual Studio 2015 _references.js UTF-16LE

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, utf-16le, references.js

In my installation of Visual Studio (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015), for MVC projecs, the `_references.js` file's character encoding is of type UTF-16LE, which prevents Git from recognizing textual differences when a change is made, treating this file as a binary one.

Is there a way, for Visual Studio, to change the character encoding of this file to avoid these conflicts?

Any help is much appreciated.

Best regards!